# Given a stress tensor, how can you find the strain rate tensor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

What is the relation between stress and strain rate? If I had this as a stress rate:

$$\mathbf \epsilon= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc}  0&  \tau_{{xy}}\ &0\\ 
 \tau_{{yx}} & gh &0\\ 0&0&2gh\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

How would you be able to derive a strain rate tensor from it? Is there an intuitive mathematical and descriptive relation between the two?

Comment: The units of the diagonal terms don't seem to match the units of the off-diagonal terms.